# someone pronounces "problem" /prɑː.ˈbləm/

Tags: pronunciation

normally, the word "problem" pronounces /ˈprɑː.bləm/,

a lecturer [in a video](https://youtu.be/pTGa9EEuZz0?list=PLdawRnR9ilZB8cHazEY1yaGptceBnY9Ht&t=88) pronounces that /prɑː.**ˈbl**əm/, is that an accent or a way to emphasize?

Comment: It seems to be a way of emphasising the word.

Comment: He's trying to emphasize that it's *problems*, and not just a single *problem*, and the same with *solutions*. I believe this is a natural way of emphasizing that, even though it comes early in the word, since the final /z/ might not be heard (and the idea conveyed clearly) if that were the only thing that were emphasized.